# Can inherited class change type of elements in base class

Tags: python, class

Assume I have classes **A1** and **A2**
and a class **B** that has elements of type A1/A2.

Now I have a class **B'(B)** (it inherits from B).
Can this class **use A1' and A2' instead of A1 and A2**,
can this new class somehow exchange the type of elements in the base class?

Normally I would say it's impossible, but since this is about python... :P

Comment: Does "elements" mean "attributes" here or something else?

Comment: What you describe sounds like standard [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) and with correct type-declarations (always declaring a supertype as reference-type) would well be possible in other languages as well, as long as `A1'` and `A2'` inherit from `A1` and `A2`.

Comment: If I need the baseclass (of B') to use A1' instead of A1, I don't see how that would be possible in C++ since I can not overwrite the baseclass elements with my own like in phyton... (maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: It's trivial in Python, because Python is fully dynamic.  In C++ terms you can (very loosely :-) ) think of it as "everything is always virtual".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
class A1(object):
    pass

class A1Child(A1):
    pass

class A2(object):
    pass

class A2Child(A2):
    pass


class B(object):

    a1_instance = None
    a2_instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.a1_instance = A1()
        self.a2_instance = A2()

class BChild(B):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a1_instance = A1Child()
        self.a2_instance = A2Child()


b_instance = B()

print b_instance.a1_instance
print b_instance.a2_instance


bchild_instance = BChild()

print bchild_instance.a1_instance
print bchild_instance.a2_instance
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the example code and I AM impressed by python. Again.